# How do I create line plots with multiple count variables in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am working on creating one plot with multiple non-discreet count variables. I have three separate count variables that are plotted by month. I have a solution but I feel that its probably not the most parsimonious and limited.

```
df_test <- structure(list(total = c(323L, 263L, 171L, 
12L, 6L, 59L, 253L, 187L, 161L, 160L, 136L, 185L, 6L), month_name = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, NA), .Label = c("Jan", 
"Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", 
"Nov", "Dec"), class = "factor"), neg = c(268L, 
231L, 146L, 10L, 6L, 55L, 237L, 177L, 140L, 131L, 107L, 155L, 
3L), pos = c(55, 32, 25, 2, 0, 4, 16, 10, 21, 
29, 29, 30, 1)), row.names = c(NA, -13L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))

ggplot() +
  geom_line(data = na.omit(df_test), aes(x=month_name, y=total), colour = "blue", group=1) +
  geom_line(data = na.omit(df_test), aes(x=month_name, y=neg), colour = "black", group=1) +
  geom_line(data = na.omit(df_test), aes(x=month_name, y=pos), colour = "red", group=1) +
  xlab("Month") +
  ylab("Count")
```

So this is what I want but I figure since the data are all in the same data frame there is probably a more parsimonious way where I can then edit a legend and also add points.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just reshape your data:

```
m <- reshape2::melt(df_test,id.vars="month_name")

ggplot(na.omit(m),aes(x=month_name,y=value,group=variable,col=variable)) +
  geom_line()
```

[image]

From here you can customize the plot as you want

Answer (score 1):

try this, this should let you edit legend names etc:

```
df_test2<-pivot_longer(df_test, cols = c("neg", "pos", "total")) %>%
  ungroup()
df_test2 %>%
  ggplot(.) + geom_point(aes(x=month_name, y = value, color = name)) +
  geom_line(aes(x=as.numeric(month_name), y = value, color = name)) +theme_classic()
```

[image]